# populating an std::[container] from a function by passing an output iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I want to populate a container from inside a function by passing an output iterator as this is the most efficient way to do it as I understand. e.g.

```
template <typename OutputIterator>
void getInts(OutputIterator it)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     *it++ = i;
}
```

([Is returning a std::list costly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092561/is-returning-a-stdlist-costly))

But how can I enforce the type, the iterator should point to ? Basically I want to say "this function takes an output iterator of type boost::tuple" .

Comment: should the output iterator be of type `boost::tuple` *always*?

Comment: yes, because I'll dereference and put in a boost::tuple object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) in conjunction with [std:iterator_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/) :

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

template <typename OutputIterator>
typename boost::enable_if<
    boost::is_same<
        int, /* replace by your type here */
        typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type
    >
>::type getInts(OutputIterator it)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     *it++ = i;
}
```

Comment: VS2010 compiler says "no instance of function template "getInts" matches the argument list" when I pass a back_inserter(int_list)

Comment: @fgungor: the iterator created from std::back_inserter, is a sink and hence does not support the value_type definition.

Comment: @Zenikoder: Ah I figured :) it defines the value_type as void. but we can get the value_type by ::container_type::value_type. We could "or" that condition into boost::enable_if maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to. The code will fail to compile *anyway* if the caller passes the wrong iterator type.

So it's enforced for you already.

Comment: If you pass a std::vector<X>.begin() it will compile but will not work correctly as you will soon overflow the container. An output iterator that is wanted here should expand the container.

Comment: Not necessarily. You may have already resized the vector to fit, and then you definitely don't want one that expands the container. In any case, as I understand the question, it is simply about how to verify that the `value_type` is compatible.