# C++ function that takes an OutputIterator and writes to it

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to write a C++ function that takes an OutputIterator and writes values to it, but I'm getting various problems. When I pass in a list<> iterator, the list is not filled, and when I pass in a vector<> iterator, I get a segmentation fault (on Linux).

I followed the discussions from ["populating an std::[container] from a function by passing an output iterator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537581/populating-an-stdcontainer-from-a-function-by-passing-an-output-iterator) and ["How to write a function that takes an iterator or collection in a generic way?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448119/how-to-write-a-function-that-takes-an-iterator-or-collection-in-a-generic-way).

Any ideas? I would like to invoke the insertValues() code with the output container's begin(), just like I would with other STL functions such std:copy().

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename OutputIterator>
void insertValues(OutputIterator result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        *(result++) = i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // This code produces 0 items in the list.
    list<int> values_list;
    insertValues(values_list.begin());
    printf("values has %d items\n", (int) values_list.size());

    // This code produces a seg fault.
    vector<int> values_vector;
    insertValues(values_vector.begin());
    printf("values has %d items\n", (int) values_vector.size());
}
```

Comment: you ask questions, but don't accept the answers. Accept answers which is most satisfying, by clicking on the "tick" sign.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code breaks, because neither the list nor the vector have enough elements. Note that an output iterator doesn't *add* elements, it simply writes to *existing* elements.

Thus, you could rewrite it as follows:

```
template<typename Container>
void insertValues(Container &result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        result.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

and in `main`:

```
insertValues(values_list);
insertValues(values_vector);
```

Alternatively, you could use an iterator that performs a `push_back` operation. This is in the standard library under the name `back_inserter` (`#include <iterator>`). Using that, and not modifying your `insertValues` code:

```
insertValues(back_inserter(values_list));
insertValues(back_inserter(values_vector));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've not seen caller code for invoking a function that uses an OutputIterator.