# Returning std::list trough an iterator NOT using templates

Tags: c++, stdlist

refering to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092561/is-returning-a-stdlist-costly/1092572#1092572), the second code block. My question is:

If I know I will be processing only `std::lists<int>`, and only `<int>`.
Is there a way to write this (the second block and the third one) without using templates and without passing the list by reference as suggested in the comments? Could you show it to me?

I think it makes sense to avoid using templates if the implementation only covers one single type right??? ( or am I too lazy? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's my answer!

You can pass a `std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<int> >` to a function with or without templates. Secretly, you're still passing the list by reference, since the iterator itself holds a reference or pointer to the container.

```
typedef std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<int> > OutputIterator;

void getInts(OutputIterator out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        *(out++) = i;
    }
}
```

Then the caller does:

```
std::list<int> l;
getInts(std::back_inserter(l));
```

You're still "using templates" in the sense that `back_inserter` is a function template, and `back_insert_iterator` is a class template, but then again so is `list`. This way you aren't writing any templates of your own.

I disagree that it necessarily makes sense to avoid templates if you're only interested in one type -- a side-effect of C++ templates is type inference via template argument deduction, meaning that you don't have to write out ridiculous types like `std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<int> >`, even once in a typedef. As you can see from the code, avoiding templates isn't laziness, it's actually less text to write the template precisely because you don't have to mention the types. But if for some reason you want to go out of your way to *restrict* that function to only work with lists, and only with appending to the back of them, then you can go ahead.

Comment: you're great! and thanks for the clarification. In the mean time I already implemented your first example in my code, and after this answer I don't think I will change it anymore. I could open another question if you want but, could you tell about the `*(out++)` part? What is this construct? Where can I read about it? Just typical iterator syntax?

Comment: @quiuquio: yeah, it's just the idiom for writing to an output iterator. It's a requirement that output iterators support it (24.1.2, table 73), but it's more-or-less equivalent to `*out = i; ++out;` -- assign the value to the dereferenced iterator, then increment it ready for the next value. I say "more or less", because it has the same defined meaning as far as the iterator interface is concerned, but there's nothing actually to stop an iterator having different side-effects for post-increment and pre-increment, or for assigning through copy vs. original, so it's not quite identical.

Comment: Oh, and the *reason* that's the idiom for iterators, is that iterators are designed as a generalization of pointers. The syntax for using an output iterator is the same as using a pointer to fill an array - write to the current element, then increment. A more object-y API might have a single function call that writes a value and steps forward in one go, but then pointers wouldn't be iterators, so C++ doesn't do it like that.